# Count unique column values in Power BI and replace them with their name and count total

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

In Power BI, how does one count the unique values in a column and replace those values with the value name and count total? Doing things this way seems like the only way to get the totals inside of a visual's legend.

Starting data example:

| Type |
| --- |
| Example1 |
| Example1 |
| Example2 |
| Example3 |
| Example2 |
| Example5 |
| Example3 |
| Example4 |
| Example1 |
| Example5 |
| Example1 |
| Example1 |
| Example2 |
| Example3 |
| Example2 |
| Example5 |
| Example3 |
| Example4 |
| Example1 |
| Example5 |
| Example1 |

Desired result:

| Type |
| --- |
| Example1 (7) |
| Example1 (7) |
| Example2 (4) |
| Example3 (4) |
| Example2 (4) |
| Example5 (4) |
| Example3 (4) |
| Example4 (2) |
| Example1 (7) |
| Example5 (4) |
| Example1 (7) |
| Example1 (7) |
| Example2 (4) |
| Example3 (4) |
| Example2 (4) |
| Example5 (4) |
| Example3 (4) |
| Example4 (2) |
| Example1 (7) |
| Example5 (4) |
| Example1 (7) |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Powerquery for it like that.

In the example I took an input table from Excel which means you have to adjust `Source` accordingly

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Tabelle1"]}[Content],
    #"Hinzugefügter Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
    groupedbyType = Table.Group(#"Hinzugefügter Index", {"Type"}, {{"CountIt", each _, type table [Type=text, Index=number]}}),
    addCol = Table.AddColumn(groupedbyType, "Count", each List.Count([CountIt][Type])),
    #"Erweiterte CountIt" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(addCol, "CountIt", {"Index"}, {"CountIt.Index"}),
    #"Hinzugefügte benutzerdefinierte Spalte" = Table.AddColumn(#"Erweiterte CountIt", "Result", each [Type] & " (" & Text.From([Count]) & ")"),
    #"Sortierte Zeilen" = Table.Sort(#"Hinzugefügte benutzerdefinierte Spalte",{{"CountIt.Index", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Entfernte Spalten" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sortierte Zeilen",{"Type", "CountIt.Index", "Count"})
in
    #"Entfernte Spalten"
```

First step in Power Query looks like
[image]

Last step looks like
[image]

What I am doing is that

- I add an index to restore the sorting later
- I group by Type but keep the rows
- I count the number of rows per group
- I extend the result
- I combine Type and the result of the count as requested
- I restore the sorting
- I remove all other columns

**Update**: Below same steps with translated steps

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Tabelle1"]}[Content],
    addedIndex = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
    groupedbyType = Table.Group(addedIndex, {"Type"}, {{"CountIt", each _, type table [Type=text, Index=number]}}),
    addCol = Table.AddColumn(groupedbyType, "Count", each Table.RowCount([CountIt])),
    extendCountIt = Table.ExpandTableColumn(addCol, "CountIt", {"Index"}, {"CountIt.Index"}),
    addedColResult = Table.AddColumn(extendCountIt, "Result", each [Type] & " (" & Text.From([Count]) & ")"),
    sortAgain = Table.Sort(addedColResult,{{"CountIt.Index", Order.Ascending}}),
    removedCol = Table.RemoveColumns(sortAgain,{"Type", "CountIt.Index", "Count"})
in
    removedCol
```

**Update for Power BI**: For Power BI the M-Code could look like that where an Excel file is used as data source.

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("Excelfilename.xlsx"), null, true),
    Table1 = Source{[Item="Tabelle1",Kind="Table"]}[Data],
    addedIndex = Table.AddIndexColumn(Table1, "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
    groupedbyType = Table.Group(addedIndex, {"Type"}, {{"CountIt", each _, type table [Type=text, Index=number]}}),
    addCol = Table.AddColumn(groupedbyType, "Count", each Table.RowCount([CountIt])),
    extendCountIt = Table.ExpandTableColumn(addCol, "CountIt", {"Index"}, {"CountIt.Index"}),
    addedColResult = Table.AddColumn(extendCountIt, "Result", each [Type] & " (" & Text.From([Count]) & ")"),
    sortAgain = Table.Sort(addedColResult,{{"CountIt.Index", Order.Ascending}}),
    removedCol = Table.RemoveColumns(sortAgain,{"Type", "CountIt.Index", "Count"})
in
    removedCol
```

Comment: Do you have an English equivalent? The German variables make it a bit difficult to follow.

Comment: Thank you! Definitely helps. One thing I notice is I can't seem to access the Power Query editor for the table. The table containing the relevant data is a calculated table. Is it possible for me to apply your steps above, or do I have to use DAX? I'm fairly new to Power BI so the separation of Dax and Power Query is fairly unintuitive.

Comment: Per your description this might not be possibe but not sure. So, I think it's best to create a new post with more details in order to get a valid answer on that.

Comment: I managed to rework things so I'm no longer using a calculated table, so I can use what you provided in Power Query, but the code doesn't seem to work. Things are okay up to `AddedIndex`, and after that, it no longer works. Where does `CountIt` come from?

Comment: `CountIt` is the name of the new column created with `Table.Group`.  What do you mean with  _after that, it no longer works_? The code as posted works for me in an Excel file.

Comment: I mean that the `Source` and `addedIndex` steps are fine, but when the others are added, the steps disappear in the Power Query editor, which based on my understanding indicates there's a problem with the code despite it passing syntax checking. If it works in Excel, is there any reason it wouldn't work in Power BI?

Comment: What does the M-Code look like in your Power BI file. I have now also tested it in Power BI using an Excel file as input. It works with no problem. Were you able to adjust the code to the Power BI environment? See update to the post.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate method

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source,"count",(i)=>Table.RowCount(Table.SelectRows(Source, each [Type]=i[Type])), type number),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom", each [Type] & " (" & Text.From([count]) & ")"),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Custom"})
in  #"Removed Other Columns"
```